# Selecting trades to maximize ownership between a variety of buy / sell weighted fields

Tags: c++, trading

Say I have four(or more) items: `beer, cheese, milk, and honey`.

And I can trade these items for other items with a percentage loss each time (due to effort). How can I select the best approach to maximize one item?

```
beer->cheese    :: buy: 10  sell: 1
beer->milk      :: buy: 5   sell: 9
beer->honey     :: buy: 4   sell: 8

cheese->beer    :: buy: 20  sell: 10
cheese->milk    :: buy: 1   sell: 15
cheese->honey   :: buy: 8   sell: 34

milk->beer      :: buy: 10  sell: 13
milk->cheese    :: buy: 7   sell: 3
milk->honey     :: buy: 8   sell: 3

honey->beer     :: buy: 110 sell: 1
honey->cheese   :: buy: 28  sell: 9
honey->milk     :: buy: 43  sell: 0.2
```

In this case I want to acquire the most beer as I am thirsty, on another day I may want to merely have a trade chain that results in the most worth. I assume I can merely bruteforce it, by looking at all of the profitable trades I am able to do, and then branching from there. I only want to make a type of trade once (e.g. cannot go sell beer for milk buy beer with milk back and forth, although selling of beer and buying of beer would be ok as long as it isn't a repeated transaction type) Is there a better way? Is there a generalized way to maximize either worth or beer?

Comment: For money, something quite similar to this is called "arbitrage". And it's not NP if the length of the transaction chain is bounded. I don't have time to write about it more now; I'm sure you can find algorithms for it out there.

Comment: @yzt it would definitely be bounded as the percentage decrease would eventually remove all options. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: Is there always a "loss percentage" involved? I mean, you can never make profits? If that is so, then the problem is even simpler.

Comment: Yes always loss percentage on each trade, but you can sometimes make profits if you can find a "good deal" by converting into something then trading that item.. is that clear?

So if I were to trade a beer for a beer I'd end up with a beer with a sip out of it. But if I was able to find someone selling a lot of milk for a small amount of cheese, and I was able to trade my beer for cheese, then trade it for milk, and someone was trading milk for beer at a decent trade I could make a profit, while simultaneously losing a few percent of that profit.. but still coming out ahead.

Comment: what market are you thinking of, @jett ?